# User upload of .swf and security

Tags: php, security, flash

I have a PHP website and I want to know if is it secure to let users upload .SWF files?

If yes, is there something I can do to make it 100% safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is dangerous to allow users to upload any files that are potentially executable in some form (be it binary or script).  Depending on the needs of the users, there may be a safe way.

As long as the users don't need to execute the .SWF but rather just store them, you can simply remove the executable bit from the file while it sits on your server.   This way the file cannot be executed on your server.

Something you will have to address though, is users uploading malicious SWFs that are targeted at *other users* instead of your server.  Even if you remove the executable bits, a user could still trick another user into downloading and executing the SWF that is stored on your server.  To fix this you should insist that users be logged in to access their files, or at least the SWF files.  This way without a valid session someone can't access it.

It is important that the files not be executed by your server.  Flash is notorious for vulnerabilities and you don't want to get Pwned by a user who uploads a malicious SWF for execution to your server.

Comment: Yes i want users to upload and "play" them, i saw some websites doing it but if like you say is not 100% secure i will find alternative. Thanks

Comment: It's a lot of work, but one thing you could do is transfer the uploaded file to a sand-boxed system, and play it.  Then re-record it based on the video output.  Then you are the one generating the file and you know there's nothing malicious.  If the file is malicious it will affect your other machine and not your server.  Use a VM in the other machine, and wipe it clean after every attempt.  Like I said it's a lot of work but that would do wonders for your safety.